# Biblatex reordering year in alphabetic bibstyle

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to create a format for my references. So far so good but i can't figure out how to put the year and the editor in parentheses after the authors without a comma. I'm using the alphabetic bibstyle. Can someone tell me how to approach this?

Here is what i have got so far:

[image]

What i'd like to have is somehting like this:

Nielsen, Jakob und Mack, Robert L. (Hrsg.) (1994): Usability inspection methods. New York, NY, USA: John Wiley & Sons, Inc.

Comment: Do you want this format just for books? There are lots of other entry types.

Comment: Well books, inproceedings and article would be enought.

Comment: And maybe misc as well if nothings fits.

Comment: What are the modifications you have applied already. Is there a chance of a full MWE (for the output above, for example)? Would you mind if this change were applied to all entry types uniformly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. It uses the `authoryear` bibliography style with the `alphabetic` citation style and then redefines to bibliography to use the alphabetic label plus the regular author/year formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
Some citations: \autocite{aksin,angenendt,aristotle:anima}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]